# ServiceStack ProtoBuf Error: Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host

Tags: servicestack

I have a ServiceStack service on a server and I am trying to run a program that connects to that service.  I am getting the intermittent error below.  This is the stack trace and anything that was below this was just the point in my program at which I was calling the server.  The most frustrating part is that it is not consistent.  If it fails and I restart the program it may fail but at a different point, it may not fail at all.  (It usually does fail again, but after a different amount of time).  Almost always it is the same call to the server I am making but I have seen it happen during other calls as well.  Any help would be greatly appreciated as this has been an issue I have been trying to solve for a while now.

```
System.AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. ---> System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException: 
ProtoBufServiceClient: 
Error deserializing: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.IO.IOException: Unable to read data from the transport connection: 
An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host. ---> 
System.Net.Sockets.SocketException: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
   at System.Net.Sockets.NetworkStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.Ensure(Int32 count, Boolean strict)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.TryReadUInt32VariantWithoutMoving(Boolean trimNegative, UInt32& value)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.TryReadUInt32Variant(UInt32& value)
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadFieldHeader()
   at proto_32(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at proto_64(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at proto_84(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at proto_56(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at proto_50(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.ProtoReader.ReadTypedObject(Object value, Int32 key, ProtoReader reader, Type type)
   at proto_78(Object , ProtoReader )
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.DeserializeCore(ProtoReader reader, Type type, Object value, Boolean noAutoCreate)
   at ProtoBuf.Meta.TypeModel.Deserialize(Stream source, Object value, Type type, SerializationContext context)
   at ProtoBuf.Serializer.Deserialize[T](Stream source)
   at ServiceStack.ProtoBuf.ProtoBufServiceClient.DeserializeFromStream[T](Stream stream)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at ServiceStack.ProtoBuf.ProtoBufServiceClient.DeserializeFromStream[T](Stream stream)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.GetResponse[TResponse](WebResponse webResponse)
   at ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase.Send[TResponse](String httpMethod, String relativeOrAbsoluteUrl, Object request)
```

Comment: The client StackTrace isn't going to help as it indicates the remote Server terminated the network connection so you'd need to look at the server (or potentially any middleware/proxies) for the cause of any failed requests. Is this happening with the latest version of ServiceStack?

Comment: Yes.  Our first thought was that this was an issue resolved in the latest version of ServiceStack so we updated both the service and client with the latest versions.